# Monitor ScheduledExecutorService in a Java web application

Tags: java, servlets, web

We have a web app with a ServletContextListener that starts several ScheduledExecutorService
to update some relaisboards via SNMP on a remote location than the server running the web application.

However it may happen that the remote relaisboards are unavailable due to a internet connection lost at the remote location.

When this happens, the thread to update the boards takes to long to execute. How can I monitor the execution and running of a ScheduledExecutorService?

Now I start the thread using this code:

```
schedulerLichtsturing = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
schedulerLichtsturing.scheduleAtFixedRate(new LichtsturingDaemon(), 0, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

However I have seen that the thread is not running anymore after some time and I don't know why it is stopping. Due to an uncaught exception or something else? How can I monitor this?

I want to also monitor the running state of the thread and the time when the last update was.

How should I fix this?

Comment: It can be tracked by the log's. Log the start time , end time and exceptions with the help of log4j and track the details periodically.

Comment: Is it true that the executor stops if an uncaught exception in the run method of the Runnable is thrown?

Comment: **If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed. Otherwise, the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the executor.** [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
private void runThrowException() throws Exception {
  throw new Exception("This allways throw an exception.");
}

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      runThrowException();
    }catch (Exception exception) {
      System.out.println("Catch exception: " + exception.toString());
    }
  }
};

ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If the sub function return an exception, the scheduled executor continue running.

I know, it doesn't hawser the monitoring question...